# Free Particle With Zero Energy (No Relativity)

Tags: energy, schroedinger-equation

Relativistic reasoning would lead one to conclude that a free particle with zero energy does not exists since it cannot have any mass given that the total energy $E = mc^2$ for any given particle at rest with nonzero mass.

I am, however, trying to show that $\Psi(x,t) = A cos(kx-\omega t)$ does not satisfy the time dependent schrodinger equation, and in this process I reach the statement that $E_k + V = 0 = E$ when considering $(x,t)=(0,0)$. I then conclude that it does not satisfy the equation since energy cannot be zero, but I don't have a non-relativistic reason for this claim that $E \neq 0$. This is problematic given that the schrodinger equation does not account for relativity, so I require another reason for my claim.

Is it possible to have a free particle with zero energy in a world without relativity, if not, how would one back up such a claim?